# Missing msvcr100.dll error while running an executable built with MinGW

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, mingw

I am successfully compiling (with MinGW) and running my C++ program (which calls Java classes through JNI) consisting of multiple files on my Win7-64bit system. Compiling and running is done by 2 batch files. I installed Visual Studio C++ 2010 some time ago but haven't used it since.

I am now trying to deploy this program to another computer running WinXP-32bit and I am facing a "missing msvcr100.dll" error. I installed the latest MinGW and JDK, I compiled my program using the same batch file, but when I'm running it, I get the error. Visual Studio is not used in any part of the building (and I don't want it to), so I find it strange that I get this message about an MSVC++ dll.

compile.bat

```
rem Set the include paths for the JNI header files("include" and "include\win32" inside the jdk (32-bit) directory).
set JDK_INCLUDE="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include"
set JDK_INCLUDE_WIN32="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32"

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin

rem Build an import library for the jvm.dll from the .\lib\jvm.def file (see http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/archive.html)
dlltool --input-def .\lib\jvm.def --kill-at --dllname jvm.dll --output-lib .\lib\libjvm.dll.a

rem Set the import library directory.
set JVM_IMPORT_DLL=".\lib"

rem Compile all files (including the IngToolTest.cpp) and create an executable file .\bin\COFORM_JNI.exe
g++ -I%JDK_INCLUDE% -I%JDK_INCLUDE_WIN32% .\src\DataTypes\file1.cpp .\src\IngestionTool\file2.cpp ... .\src\file25.cpp Test.cpp -L%JVM_IMPORT_DLL% -ljvm -o .\bin\executable.exe

pause
```

run.bat

```
Rem Set the environment parameter to the path where the properties file resides.
set CONFIG_DIR=..

Rem Set the environment parameter to the actual IP of your VM machine.
set VM_URL=139.191.173.43

Rem Set the location of the jvm.dll (32-bit)
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\client

move *.rdf RDFS

.\bin\executable.exe

pause
```

Is it possible that one of my external includes is causing this? Here they are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

I would appreciate any help to overcome this error.

K

Answer (score 5):

While MinGW is a distribution of GCC, to allow it to run natively on Windows without having a Linux emulation layer like Cygwin it does not use the GNU C library.  Instead it uses Microsoft's C Runtime.  I have not used MinGW for a while, when it used MSVCRT.DLL from VC++ 6.0, which was more or less ubiquitous in Windows installations at the time as it shipped with installations since late Win95 editions.

It is quite possible that your installation of Windows does not have the later runtime if it was not distributed with it and you have not installed any application with which it was distributed.  It may be that you have only the 64 bit DLL and need to install the 32 bit DLL.

The simple solution is to install Microsoft's VC++ re-distributable package(s).

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

---

**Added Note:**  According to both http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.mingw.org, MinGW still depends on MSVCRT.DLL, so I wonder what you have done or where you obtained your distribution that makes it depend on MSVCRT100.DLL?  Some experimental build perhaps?

Comment: Important note everyone seems to *not* know: msvcrt.dll != VC 6.0. It's updated with each major OS update (including service packs) and is very comparable to glibc on Linux. Also an important detail: a lot of the C standard library is re-implemented in MinGW(-w64), and in the case of MinGW-w64 that implementation is very fast.

Comment: I deployed my program to another computer using WinXP-32bit and everything works just fine using the same MinGW compiler and JDK 1.6 (instead of 1.7 which the first computer was using). I suppose something is horribly wrong at the first computer. I knew that my problems would be solved after installing the redistributable package (and they did) but I still can't figure out why this dll is requested. Thanx anyway guys. And by the way, MSVCRT.DLL is present

Comment: @rubenvb:  I am not sure that it was *that* important to note, however yes like any system DLL it is subject to update with versions of Windows and via Windows Update.  Nonetheless, it originally shipped with VC++6 and not with the OS; early releases of Windows 95 did not include it.

Comment: Clifford: Windows 95 != Windows As We Use It in this day and age. Your statement misleads an uninformed user about the state and quality of code produced by MinGW compilers.

Comment: @rubenvb:  Ah I see your point; it was not my intention to suggest that MSVCRT.DLL was old or inferior, merely that it was ubiquitous due to its long standing inclusion in Windows installations.  However your suggestion is to presume that if it was from Windows 95 then it must be poor quality, but the standard  C library is a very simple thing and very mature technology even then, so even if it were the same old C library, that would hardly be to its detriment in any case.  I dare say hardly any of it has changed significantly over the years.

Comment: Clifford: I would think the glibc devs would disagree as to the maturity of a basic C implementation... I was only pointing out to the masses what you said in this last comment :)

Comment: @ribenvb:  Maybe, but glibc encompasses much more than just the standard library, it is also the core OS API for linux (encompassing in terfaces defined by Single UNIX Specification, POSIX, ISO C99, BSD, System V Interface Definition, and X/Open) so requires more maintenance.  The scope of MSVCRT is much smaller.

Answer (score 2):

The DLL contains the runtime for compiled programs. It must be installed on the other machine to be able to run the program.

Standard program distributions have an install package that does this for you, or you can install it manually.

See here for download instructions

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: Why do I need this? I haven't used MSVC++ throughout the whole project. Can't I run it without the dll?

Comment: MinGW uses the native C and C++ runtime on Windows, where MSVCR100 is the latest release (10.0). You might possibly configure it to use one of the old versions present on XP (but I don't know exactly how).

Answer (score -2):

MinGW merely emulates Linux OS calls. Let me explain..

When you ceate a binary that runs on a certain OS, that binary needs to know how to interact with the underlying OS. This is important for things like memory allocation. The binary doesn't natively "know" how to allocate RAM, instead, it asks the host OS to give it some RAM. It does this, by calling an allocation function that resides at a predetermined "address" inside the OS.

**How does the application know what "address" the allocation method exists at?**

When you compile the binary, you bind to it a "C runtime library (CRT)". This library contains all the mappings for OS interactions that the binary will need. So for example, when you link the CRT, the binary now knows where it can find the memory allocation function that is exposed by the OS.

MinGW, inserts an emulation layer such that an application thinks its linking to a Linux CRT, but really, the emulation layer just redirects calls to the Microsoft CRT.

Windows, has a number of different CRTs available. On all distributions, you can find somewhere in `%PATH%`, the file `msvcrt.dll`. This file, provides all support that a binary would need to run in the OS.

When you install Visual Studio, you get updated versions of the CRT:

1. In VS 2005: msvcrt80.dll
2. In VS 2008: msvcrt90.dll
3. In VC 2010: msvcrt100.dll

Apparently, by installing Visual Studio, you've caused MinGW's emulation layer to link against `msvcrt100.dll`, rather than the `msvcrt.dll`, that comes distributed on all windows machines. I don't know why this is happening, but this **IS** what is happening.

**EDIT**

The command:

```
dlltool --input-def .\lib\jvm.def --kill-at --dllname jvm.dll --output-lib .\lib\libjvm.dll.a
```

Which is producing a file that links in `jvm.dll` might creating the `msvcrt100.dll` dependency. That is, `jvm.dll` might be dynamically linked against the newest CRT, and because you require `jvm.dll` you indirectly need `msvcrt100.dll`.

Are there any dll's found in ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"?

Comment: It does not emulate Linux calls at all; that is what Cygwin does.  MinGW includes some compatibility headers where there are exact or near equivalents in MSVCRT but makes no attempt at emulation.  MinGW applications directly access the MSVCRT.  That is why for example fork() is not available; that process model is not supported natively by Windows.  The toolchain itself does use a DLL to provide enough support to allow the GNU toolchain code itself to run, but applications built with it do not depend on this.

Comment: This answer is wrong on every point pertinent to the question.